# ASN.1 reading material

Tags: c, asn.1

Is there any place where i could get some materials to know about ASN.1.
I want to know about the syntax's to be used and also some examples to get some overview.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the [ASN1C](http://lionet.info/asn1c/) documentation and examples to be very useful in the past.

Comment: I didn't see anything there on PER.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few more or less free documents on ASN.1.

A good short intro is [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/layman.asc), especially if you need it in the context of X.509 or similar stuff.

Another good resource would be the book from Olivier Dubuisson which can be downloaded after a free of charge registration from: [ASN.1 Reference Book](http://www.oss.com/asn1/dubuisson.html) , another book there is from John Larmouth [ASN.1 Complete](http://www.oss.com/asn1/larmouth.html), might also be worth a look.

You can also go in depth with the appropriate standards documents from the ISO, but those tend to be rather cryptic, you can find all the references at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#References

Answer (score 0):

the official standards are called `X.680` and `X.690`

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to start at A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1 but if you have some konwledge on asn1 syntax then for practice or understanding you can make some sample on http://asn1-playground.oss.com/

This online tool help me a lot. Thanks.